# Non resourcefull route with bound parameter not clear. Not getting its behaviour

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have route defined in my routes.rb

```
get ':conroller(/:action)' => 'show/show_all#test'
```

and in my ruby file i have following link

```
<td><%= link_to 'Test non resourcefull route:show', :controller="fdsfdsf" :action="fdsfds" %></td>`enter code here`
```

after executing the link i am able to see my

> test.html.erb

file even though the spelling of controller is wrong in my route definition. But if i correct the spelling to 'Controller' i get following error

> uninitialized constant ShowAllController.

Please clear this behavior.